# How to get daily query count on mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to generate a report where I can present the count of queries processed by my sql servers on a daily basis. Is there any way I can get the count or any log file where I can count the queries processed.

Comment: This question has an answer on the dba site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/how-to-determine-mysql-queries-per-day

Comment: Thank you. But are there any updates on the answers based on his question aside from manually computing the count of queries on a daily interval?

Comment: You can schedule the run of the query within or outside of mysql ensuring consistency of the numbers. Obviously, if you need to restart the server, then you have to manually take the count.